# Combine server side exporting and client side exporting in Highcharts (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, charts, highcharts

I was using Highcharts' export server to download charts as an image. I need to use the client-side(offline) exporting feature in a single chart due to the count of data points in the chart. After I use client-side exporting in just one chart, all of the charts turn into client-side exporting. How can I use both client-side exporting and Highcharts' export server in the same project?

Here is the relevant parts from the source code:

`client-side-exporting-chart.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <chart :options="chartOptions" ref="chart" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";
import offlineExporting from "highcharts/modules/offline-exporting";

offlineExporting(Highcharts);

export default {
  // ...
  components:{
    Chart
  },
  data(){
    return {
       chartOptions: {
         // ...
         exporting:{
           // ...
           fallbackToExportServer:false
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

`export-server-chart.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <chart :options="chartOptions" ref="chart" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";
import exportingInit from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

exportingInit(Highcharts);

export default {
  // ...
  components:{
    Chart
  },
  data(){
    return {
       chartOptions: {
         // ...
         exporting:{
           // ...
           fallbackToExportServer:true
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are initialized globally and since you have only one Highcharts instance in your project, offline-exporting is auto-enabled for each component.

Under the hood, the module redefines `menuItemDefinitions` and uses `exportChartLocal` instead of `exportChart` method. You can simply reverse back this behaviour for individual charts, by adding the below configuration:

```
  exporting: {
    menuItemDefinitions: {
      downloadPNG: {
        textKey: 'downloadPNG',
        onclick: function() {
          this.exportChart();
        }
      },
      downloadJPEG: {
        textKey: 'downloadJPEG',
        onclick: function() {
          this.exportChart({
            type: 'image/jpeg'
          });
        }
      },
      downloadPDF: {
        textKey: 'downloadPDF',
        onclick: function() {
          this.exportChart({
            type: 'application/pdf'
          });
        }
      },
      downloadSVG: {
        textKey: 'downloadSVG',
        onclick: function() {
          this.exportChart({
            type: 'image/svg+xml'
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bgk5ftaj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.menuItemDefinitions

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But is there an alternate way to use both client side exporting and server side exporting without adding extra configurations?

Comment: Hi @yasinkuyuk, Unfortunately, there is no single option to switch between basic and offline exporting. But alternatively, you can create a small plugin and implement such an option, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/74f9w3eo/